# Which API does `docker node ps` call?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

`docker node ps` allows the manager node to determine what is being run in other nodes of the swarm.  My question is which API does it call

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#tag/Node

Only has listing of the nodes, but there's nothing that would list what is running except for [/containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ContainerList) but that only lists the ones running in the current node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operation/TaskList` is called by Docker CLI for all nodes ([source code](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/ae1618713f83e7da07317d579d0675f578de22fa/cli/command/node/ps.go#L79)).

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/TaskList